# Accessing $state outside angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, hybrid-mobile-app, url-template

I have an angularjs application. The app is supposed to be a hybrid mobile app for android and iOS. I have a JavaScript file in the project which is not a part of any module. In that JavaScript file I need to call the respective template URL, either through $state or any method which loads the controller also.

For $scope I found many ways of accessing it outside that angularjs project but could not find the same for $state.

Comment: this question isn't very clear.  Why are you needing this information outside an angular context?  And what would non-angular code do with a template URL that is only a partial view that hasn't been rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we can use java-script

```
window.location.href //to change location
```

for example:
 suppose right now I am in https://www.google.co.in/

now i want to navigate to https://news.google.co.in/

we can simply write

```
window.location.href ="https://news.google.co.in/"
```

it will navigate to that page

Now in your project you might have defined your routing like this

```
function routeConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
$stateProvider
  .state('landing.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: "app/components/homeFolder/home.html",
    controller: 'homeController',
    controllerAs: 'homec'
  })
  .state('landing.hometwo', {
    url: '/home1',
    templateUrl: "app/components/OnHand/Templates/OnHandhome.html",
    controller: 'OnHandController',
    controllerAs: 'Onhand'
  })

  })
```

Now  if you are in angularjs controller you will simply use

```
 $state.go('landing.home');// to navigate to your required location
```

But if you are not in angularjs Module you can change window.location to navigate to required page

for example to achieve ---$state.go('landing.home'); you can write

```
window.location.href ="https:complete url"
```

or otherwise

```
window.location.hash ="#/home1" //the url which is defined for that state
```